# intent to next activity, toast, progress bar not working

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-intent

I am trying to make a login page where if user enters a correct mobile and pwd it should go in ProfileActivity.java

**my code**

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText editTextUsername, editTextPassword;
ProgressBar progressBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    if (SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).isLoggedIn()) {
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(this, ProfileActivity.class));
    }

    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    editTextUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUsername);
    editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);


    //if user presses on login
    //calling the method login
    Button login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);
    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            userLogin();
        }
    });

    //if user presses on not registered
    findViewById(R.id.textViewRegister).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //open register screen
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
        }
    });
}

private void userLogin() {
    //first getting the values
    final String mobile = editTextUsername.getText().toString();
    final String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();

    //validating inputs
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mobile)) {
        editTextUsername.setError("Please enter your username");
        editTextUsername.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
        editTextPassword.setError("Please enter your password");
        editTextPassword.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    //if everything is fine
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URLs.URL_LOGIN,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    try {
                        //converting response to json object
                        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);

                        //if no error in response
                        if (!obj.getBoolean("error")) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            //getting the user from the response
                            JSONObject userJson = obj.getJSONObject("user");

                            //creating a new user object
                            User user = new User(
                                    userJson.getInt("id"),
                                    userJson.getString("mobile"),
                                    userJson.getString("password")
                            );

                            //storing the user in shared preferences
                            SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).userLogin(user);

                            //starting the profile activity

                            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), obj.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Log.e("TAG", response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("mobile", mobile);
            params.put("password", password);
            return params;
        }
    };

    VolleySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
}
}
```

In this code neither a toast, progressbar, nor the intent to redirect to next activity is working. I have also extended ProfileActivity with Activity. I have registerd profileactivity.java in manifest file.

What am i doing wrong here? thank you for your suggestions

Comment: try debugging the code !! is onResponse getting called ?? successfully ??

Comment: in the stack trace   "new Response.Listener<String>() {"     is highlighted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. In the line ,

```
JSONObject userJson = obj.getJSONObject("user");
```

I named the object as user. But in PHP I named it as result As soon as I changed it, it started working.

Although, Thanks for your support community :).

Answer (score 0):

finish() method should be put a end, because it will ignore all next lines.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Comment: Log to view respond string?

Comment: I think it has something to do with inResponce() since in the stack trace "new Response.Listener<String>() {" is highlighted

Comment: Log.e("TAG", response); outside of try catch to check json string and you can update your question.

Comment: shows E/TAG: {"result":[{"userid":"23","access":"Allowed"}]}

Comment: obj.getBoolean("error") will occur exception because `error` not map

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167502/discussion-between-meoscoder-and-yaseef-sheikh).

Comment: You should delete `if (!obj.getBoolean("error"))` because your reponse string have no 'error' key

Comment: Json parse from `{"result":[{"userid":"23","access":"Allowed"}]}` have no `id`, `mobile` and `password` key

Answer (score 0):

You are using "id" field as an integer and it's an String ,Secondly from where you are getting

```
User user = new User(
                                userJson.getString("id"),
                           "",              // please add mobile and password in JSON
                           ""
                        );
```